# Bash: How to call a function based on the its input argument?

Tags: bash

I define two functions in a bash script `say.sh`. I would like `./say.sh hello` calls hello(), and `./say.sh hi` calls hi(). What is the bash-y way to do it?

```
#!/bin/bash

hello(){
    echo "hello"
}


hi(){
    echo "hi"
}
```

Comment: `$1` should call the function that is given as first parameter.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYkxDoAgEMD2e8WJDjoR3@BLAFEuQTAIJsb49pM42q2tVodjbhupKUhdBcBZ72M/3IAVa1xE8SUBD9RLv0Vfb3FS3uNSgskUA@4pnjTbGfWFC6Ujo0pr2WzI0I3M7OgF "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: I like you link, @0stone0.